# HTTP gateway timeout

Tags: http, networking

When I tried to request the data across the internet through a web service I received an error as:

```
Error: The request failed with HTTP status 504: Gateway Time-out.
```

Can anyone please give an insight about this error, and a solution too? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is some proxy (reverse proxy, HTTP server with FastCGI or something similar) in the way, which timeouted when getting request from the server.